# What happens to my PDO-object when I put it inside a function?

Tags: php, object

I have a object called $db, it outputs other stuff when it's inside a function:

```
<?php
$dsn = "pgsql:"
    . "host=ec2-54-217-239-27.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;"
    . "dbname=dat08vv8oqt1j1;"
    . "user=secret :);"
    . "port=5432;"
    . "sslmode=require;"
    . "password=secret :)";

$db = new PDO($dsn);
$sql = "create table parent_children (
    parent_path varchar,
    child_path varchar,
    primary key(parent_path,child_path),
    foreign key (parent_path) references nodes (path),
    foreign key (child_path) references nodes (path)
)";
/*$sq = $db ->query($sql);*/

print_r($db);
myqueries($sql, $db);

function myqueries($myobject, $sql){
    print_r($myobject);
    die();
};
```

the first time it outputs

```
PDO Object ( )
```

The next time:

```
create table parent_children ( parent_path varchar, child_path varchar, primary key(parent_path,child_path), foreign key (parent_path) references nodes (path), foreign key (child_path) references nodes (path) )
```

The problem is that this won't work inside the function:

```
$sq = $myobject ->query($sql);
```

But it works outside of it.

Comment: In the code above, you're passing `$sql` as the first parameter, but the function is expecting the connection as the first parameter and the SQL as the second one. Maybe try swapping them around?

Comment: `myqueries($sql, $db)` should be the other way around: `myqueries($db, $sql)`. That's what [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in PHP is for, btw: have you defined this function as `myqueries(PDO $myobject, $sql)`, the compiler would have caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function args.  Try:

`myqueries($db, $sql);`

From raina77ow's comment:

`function myqueries(PDO $myobject, $sql) {}`

Will throw an error if $myobject is not of type PDO.